# Python subprocess callback another py script

Tags: python, subprocess

I use `subprocess.Popen(['python', 'test.py'])` to call another script
How to get callback from another python script to main in Flask?
My code is

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main():

    global process

    if request.method == 'POST':

        index = request.form['index']

        if index == 'start':
            process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'test.py'])

        if index == 'stop':

            ###
            # after click stop btn i want to get array from another py script
            ###

            process.kill()

        return redirect(url_for('main'))

    return render_template('index.html')

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: you can execute a function from `test.py` and import the file into the flask file. in the `test.py` you simply return something which then get's saved in the variable in the flask route. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: you mean add `import test.py` in main script?

Comment: yes @Dmitry from there on you can do something like `another.foo()` which then returns an result you defined in your `another.py` file

Comment: Why are you using subprocess? Python code should generally *import* other Python code and call it, not execute it as a separate process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that `test.py` file is infinite loop returning current date:

```py
# test.py

from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

i = 0
while True:
  i += 1
  print(f'"now_{i}": "{datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M-%S")}",')
  sleep(5)
```

output:

```
"now_1": "11-48-22",
"now_2": "11-48-27",
"now_3": "11-48-32",
...
```

Flask application code should be like:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import subprocess
import signal
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

process = None


def control_proc(action):

  global process

  if action == 'start':
    process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'test.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    return None
  elif action == 'stop':
   if process is None:
     return b'', b'Run process first'
   else:
     try:
       # if windows
       if os.name == 'nt':
         process.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
       # if linux
       else:
         process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
       return process.communicate(timeout=2)
     except ValueError:
       return b'', b'Looks like process already stopped'
  else:
    raise Exception(f'Bad command: {action}')


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main():
  return '<html><a href="/start">START</a><br><a href="/stop">STOP</a></html>'


@app.route('/start', methods=['GET'])
def start():
  control_proc("start")
  return '{"status": "started"}'

@app.route('/stop', methods=['GET'])
def stop():

  result = control_proc("stop")

  return '{"status": "stopped", "output": {' + result[0].decode("utf-8").rstrip(",\n") + '}' + ', "error": "' + result[1].decode("utf-8").replace('"', '') + '"}'

app.run(debug=True)
```

When you access `http://127.0.0.1:5000/start` `process` will be started

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/stop` url stop the `process` and print `process` output

```json
{
  "status": "stopped",
  "output": {
    "now_1": "11-59-41",
    "now_2": "11-59-46",
    "now_3": "11-59-51",
    "now_4": "11-59-56",
    "now_5": "12-00-01",
    "now_6": "12-00-06",
    "now_7": "12-00-11",
    "now_8": "12-00-16",
    "now_9": "12-00-21",
    "now_10": "12-00-26",
    "now_11": "12-00-31"
  },
  "error": "Traceback (most recent call last): File test.py, line 8, in sleep(5) KeyboardInterrupt "
}
```